# Eloquent: Create relation if not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Subscriptions table: id, client_id, status, valid_until
Clients talbe: id, name

Model Client.php:

```
public function subscription { 
  return $this->hasOne(Subscription::class) 
}
```

I would like to use `$client->subscription->start()` to:

1. If a previous relation already exist: `status=1, valid_until \now()+addDays(30)`
2. if relation does not exist create subscription row with above data.

Is it possible?
Or do I have to build a static function in subscription.php. ex: `Subscription::start($client)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models with adapt to your requirements.